# How many pizzas possible?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Consider the following pizza deal:

• $3$ pizzas

• up to $3$ toppings on each pizza

• $8$ toppings to choose from

The pizza toppings need not be unique—double or triple toppings of the same kind are allowed; i.e.,

$2$ or $3$ of the toppings can be the same. (Note that double or triple toppings are not required, but they
are allowed.)

A pizza with no toppings also is allowed. The two pizzas may or may not be identical.
The arrangement of the toppings on each pizza does not matter; e.g., tomatoes on top of pepperoni is
the same as pepperoni on top of tomatoes.
What is the total number of possibilities for a pizza order in this deal?

My attempt

First, consider the case where the toppings are unique. 
Let x be the total number of ways of choosing one pizza.
$x =8C_0+8C_1+8C_2+8C_3$

Now consider the case where double or triple toppings of the same kind are allowed Let x be the total number of ways of choosing one pizza. In addition to
the count above, there are 8 ways of choosing a two-topping pizza with 2 identical toppings, 8 ways
of choosing a three topping pizza with 3 identical toppings (and 8 ways for 4 identical and 5 identical but thats besides the point), and P(8, 2) ways of choosing a three topping pizza with two identical toppings and one different topping. (This is a part I am confused at... ie why must it be P(8,2) and not C(8,2)

Then for one pizza we have:
$x =8c_0+8c_1+8c_2+8c_3+ 8 + 8 + (8 × 7)(\text{ ie } 8p_2)$

Then if $y =$ total for all three we have
$y = x +(xc_3)$
because we want three
(This is another part I am confused on)

???

Comment: Are toppings unlimited, i.e. can we use the same topping, three times, in all three pizzas?

Comment: I believe we can

Comment: You have correctly found the number of toppings for one pizza.  To obtain the number of ways of ordering three pizzas, just cube your result.  As for the triple topping consisting of a double topping and a single topping, there are $8$ ways to select the double topping and seven ways to select the single topping, so there are $8 \cdot 7 = 56$ possible orders for this case.

Answer (score 1):

Let 8 toppings $\rm{A,B,C ...H}$. If you chose $x_1$ toppings of flavour $\rm A \, , x_2$ of flavour $\rm B$, $x_3$ of flavour $\rm C$, and so on...

Since, you want total number of toppings to be less than, or equal to $3.$ we have the equation

$$x_1+x_2+\cdots + x_8 \le 3$$

Where all $x_i$ are non-negative integers. Once you find solution of this inequation, just cube the answer.

Comment: no please explain

Comment: @rajteh You can see my edit now.

Comment: and if you had only 2 pizzas you would square the answer?

Comment: oh how do you differentiate between if you want 2 pizzas 3 pizzas 4 pizzas?

Comment: @rajteh  The number of solutions of the inequality is the number of ways the toppings for one pizza can be ordered.   If you wish to select $n$ pizzas, you raise the result to the $n$th power.

Comment: Thanks @N. F. Taussig for explaining from my side :)

Comment: Simply raising the answer for 1 pizza by number of pizzas considers each pizza (if I'm not mistaken) as essentially separate entities and does not  account for instances of duplicate[s]. Depending how they are rung-up on the receipt, it could be listed corresponding to the simpler formula, but the actual number of unique combinations of pizzas possible (not assigning any particular pizza of the three a unique customer name, just stating its toppings) would be smaller. I'm not sure what the exact formula is yet or even if the simpler one is correct. I got to give it a think.

Comment: @victamon If you consider ordered entries, then yeah, raising to power might count duplicates. Say me and you are eating Pizzas. Me eating a triple-veggie topping and you eating two single-topping Margherita, and vice versa is counted as two in raising power; while it is just a single unique combination. However, thanks for pinging me on an old question. I visit the website quite less frequently since past 2 years or so.